# Anaconda Navigator does not update packages

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to update my environment through Anaconda Navigator. But it fails to update some packages. As you can see, the Apply button is inactive and there is a message saying "Package is already installed" but the package is still in Updatable page. Also, Spyder tells me to update nbconvert at each start.

[image: Error message]

I tried:

- conda update conda
- conda update anaconda-navigator
- conda update navigator-updater
- conda update --all -y

But still these packages are in Updatable list.

This is the conda info output:

```
C:\Users\user>conda info

     active environment : None
       user config file : C:\Users\user\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\user\.condarc
          conda version : 4.6.8
    conda-build version : 3.17.8
         python version : 3.6.8.final.0
       base environment : C:\Users\ismetb\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\user\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\user\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.6.8 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.6.8 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17134
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is everything in **base** environment or do you have multiple envs?

Comment: I have a separate environment but updates do not work for both base and ai (my env)

Comment: Can you manually verify that the packages are indeed not updated? I.e., check the versions with `conda list -n base` and `conda list -n ai`.  If they are the latest versions, then maybe it'd be worth trying `conda install nbconvert --force-reinstall`.

Comment: I could not solve the problem so I deleted Anaconda and did a fresh install

Comment: Even fresh install did not work. I'm still getting "nbconvert" warning (even though it is up to date). Maybe I should switch to Miniconda

Comment: Have you tried posting on [the Anaconda Issues](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues)?  I mean, switching to Miniconda you're just not going to use Navigator anyway (unless you really want to). Personally, I think most users should be using Miniconda, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: @merv The error is gone after I deleted .anaconda directory and did a fresh install. But it is still weird that the updatable tab never gets empty.

Comment: I also have the same problem. This is not the first case.

Comment: This is happening to me a year later on a fresh anaconda install. :thumbsup:

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution I found to work is the [alternative method](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/update-navigator/) found on the anaconda site.

In the terminal type:

```
conda deactivate
```

followed by:

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

Other solutions updated the packages but not Anaconda Navigator itself. In your case, it seems the issue might have been not deactivating first.

Comment: I am already on latest Navigator version but still have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Got the similar problem. Solved by command line "*conda update anaconda*" in line with [Anaconda Troubleshooting](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/troubleshooting/#conda-update-anaconda-command-does-not-install-the-latest-version-of-anaconda)

Answer (score -1):

What anurag said worked for me but I'll explain it differently.

I left clicked on the package name and then at the bottom I could choose which package I wanted to update. I chose the latest and then it updated. For some reason the commands "conda update anaconda" and "conda update python" didn't see the latest and update my version. It only tried to update the installed version.

Answer (score -1):

The below worked for me when I ran it on the anaconda command prompt:

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda-navigator
conda update navigator-updater
```

Comment: This was stated in the question and did not work.

Comment: In the question they also used "conda update --all -y" I didn't as stated in my answer. Also, as I mention in my answer this is just what worked for me while not including "conda update --all -y".

Answer (score -1):

my problem solved after installing OpenSSL in Anaconda Powershell Prompt

```
conda install -c anaconda openssl
```

Answer (score -10):

In anaconda navigator:

1. right click on the package
2. then select specific function
3. then apply.

The problem should be resolved by now.