# Anaconda navigator not refreshing packages that have been updated with terminal

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Good day,

I am trying to update my packages in the base and anaconda3 environments using the Anaconda Navigator with the following steps:

1. Select the required environment to update
2. Select the packages that need to be updated – “Updatable”
3. Clicked “Update Index”
4. Clicked the play button next to the environment and opened the terminal
5. Run `conda update –all`
6. All packages updated

When I then refresh the respective environment in the navigator, it still shows that there are 20 and 21 packages available to be updated respectively.

I then followed the approach in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55144561/anaconda-navigator-does-not-update-packages):

```
conda deactivate
```

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

I then uninstalled and reinstalled the navigator using the instructions [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/install/):

```
conda remove anaconda-navigator
```

```
conda install anaconda-navigator
```

I have restarted my Mac, terminal and the navigator and still have the same result.

Is the warning message in the screenshot causing the issue?

[image]

I have also run the following and it looks like the packages are up to date, but its not reflecting in the navigator.

```
conda list -n base
```

[image]