# can't import packages installed before, such as matplotlib, after i update python using conda

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, conda

i want to use the matplotlib.pyplot.figure.supxlabel in my jupyter notebook，and it needs:

1. Python version at least 3.7
2. matplotlib version at least 3.4

but version on my computer is python 3.6.12 and matplotlib 3.3.4

so i use `conda update python`, and now my python version is 3.9.7

but i can't import packages installed before, such like matplotlib and scipy. Could anybody tell me why, i would appreciate it a lot.
[ModuleNotFoundError:No module named 'matplotlib'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0XMN.jpg)

and when i try`conda list --show-channel-urls` , i got this:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0            py39hecd8cb5_0    defaults
anaconda-client           1.9.0            py39hecd8cb5_0    defaults
anaconda-navigator        2.1.1                    py39_0    defaults
anyio                     2.2.0            py39hecd8cb5_1    defaults
appnope                   0.1.2           py39hecd8cb5_1001    defaults
argon2-cffi               20.1.0           py39h9ed2024_1    defaults
async_generator           1.10               pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
attrs                     21.2.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
babel                     2.9.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
backcall                  0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
beautifulsoup4            4.10.0             pyh06a4308_0    defaults
blas                      1.0                         mkl    defaults
bleach                    4.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
brotli                    1.0.9                hb1e8313_2    defaults
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py39h9ed2024_1003    defaults
bzip2                     1.0.8                h1de35cc_0    defaults
ca-certificates           2021.10.26           hecd8cb5_2    defaults
certifi                   2021.10.8        py39hecd8cb5_0    defaults
cffi                      1.14.6           py39h2125817_0    defaults
chardet                   4.0.0           py39hecd8cb5_1003    defaults
charset-normalizer        2.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
clyent                    1.2.2            py39hecd8cb5_1    defaults
conda                     4.11.0           py39hecd8cb5_0    defaults
conda-build               3.21.7           py39hecd8cb5_0    defaults
conda-content-trust       0.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
conda-package-handling    1.7.3            py39h9ed2024_1    defaults
conda-repo-cli            1.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
conda-token               0.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
cryptography              3.4.8            py39h2fd3fbb_0    defaults
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
debugpy                   1.5.1            py39he9d5cce_0    defaults
decorator                 5.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
entrypoints               0.3              py39hecd8cb5_0    defaults
filelock                  3.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
fonttools                 4.25.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
freetype                  2.11.0               hd8bbffd_0    defaults
giflib                    5.2.1                haf1e3a3_0    defaults
glob2                     0.7                pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
gmp                       6.2.1                h23ab428_2    defaults
gmpy2                     2.0.8            py39h4b98818_3    defaults
h5py                      3.6.0            py39h4a1dd59_0    defaults
hdf5                      1.10.6               hdbbcd12_0    defaults
icu                       58.2                 h0a44026_3    defaults
idna                      3.3                pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
importlib-metadata        4.8.2            py39hecd8cb5_0    defaults
importlib_metadata        4.8.2                hd3eb1b0_0    defaults
intel-openmp              2021.4.0          hecd8cb5_3538    defaults
ipykernel                 6.4.1            py39hecd8cb5_1    defaults
ipython                   7.29.0           py39h01d92e1_0    defaults
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1    defaults
ipywidgets                7.6.5              pyhd3eb1b0_1    defaults
jedi                      0.18.0           py39hecd8cb5_1    defaults
jinja2                    2.11.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
jpeg                      9d                   h9ed2024_0    defaults
json5                     0.9.6              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
jsonschema                3.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2    defaults
jupyter_client            7.0.6              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
jupyter_core              4.9.1            py39hecd8cb5_0    defaults
jupyter_server            1.4.1            py39hecd8cb5_0    defaults
jupyterlab                3.2.1              pyhd3eb1b0_1    defaults
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0    defaults
jupyterlab_server         2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
jupyterlab_widgets        1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1    defaults
kiwisolver                1.3.1            py39h23ab428_0    defaults
lcms2                     2.12                 hf1fd2bf_0    defaults
libarchive                3.4.2                haa3ed63_0    defaults
libcxx                    12.0.0               h2f01273_0    defaults
libffi                    3.3                  hb1e8313_2    defaults
libgfortran               3.0.1                h93005f0_2    defaults
libiconv                  1.16                 h1de35cc_0    defaults
liblief                   0.10.1               h23ab428_1    defaults
libllvm11                 11.1.0               h9b2ccf5_0    defaults
libpng                    1.6.37               ha441bb4_0    defaults
libsodium                 1.0.18               h1de35cc_0    defaults
libtiff                   4.2.0                h87d7836_0    defaults
libwebp                   1.2.0                hacca55c_0    defaults
libwebp-base              1.2.0                h9ed2024_0    defaults
libxml2                   2.9.12               hcdb78fc_0    defaults
llvm-openmp               12.0.0               h0dcd299_1    defaults
llvmlite                  0.37.0           py39he4411ff_1    defaults
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h23ab428_1    defaults
markupsafe                2.0.1            py39h9ed2024_0    defaults
matplotlib                3.5.0            py39hecd8cb5_0    defaults
matplotlib-base           3.5.0            py39h4f681db_0    defaults
matplotlib-inline         0.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_2    defaults
mistune                   0.8.4           py39h9ed2024_1000    defaults
mkl                       2021.4.0           hecd8cb5_637    defaults
mkl-service               2.4.0            py39h9ed2024_0    defaults
mkl_fft                   1.3.1            py39h4ab4a9b_0    defaults
mkl_random                1.2.2            py39hb2f4e1b_0    defaults
mpc                       1.1.0                h6ef4df4_1    defaults
mpfr                      4.0.2                h9066e36_1    defaults
mpmath                    1.2.1            py39hecd8cb5_0    defaults
munkres                   1.1.4                      py_0    defaults
navigator-updater         0.2.1            py39hecd8cb5_0    defaults
nbclassic                 0.2.6              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
nbclient                  0.5.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
nbconvert                 6.1.0            py39hecd8cb5_0    defaults
nbformat                  5.1.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
ncurses                   6.3                  hca72f7f_2    defaults
nest-asyncio              1.5.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
notebook                  6.4.6            py39hecd8cb5_0    defaults
numba                     0.54.1           py39hae1ba45_0    defaults
numpy                     1.20.3           py39h4b4dc7a_0    defaults
numpy-base                1.20.3           py39he0bd621_0    defaults
olefile                   0.46               pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
openssl                   1.1.1l               h9ed2024_0    defaults
packaging                 21.3               pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
pandocfilters             1.4.3            py39hecd8cb5_1    defaults
parso                     0.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3    defaults
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003    defaults
pillow                    8.4.0            py39h98e4679_0    defaults
pip                       21.2.4           py39hecd8cb5_0    defaults
pkginfo                   1.7.1            py39hecd8cb5_0    defaults
prometheus_client         0.12.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
prompt-toolkit            3.0.20             pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
psutil                    5.8.0            py39h9ed2024_1    defaults
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2    defaults
py-lief                   0.10.1           py39h23ab428_1    defaults
pycosat                   0.6.3            py39h9ed2024_0    defaults
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
pygments                  2.10.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
pyjwt                     2.1.0            py39hecd8cb5_0    defaults
pyopenssl                 21.0.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1    defaults
pyparsing                 3.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
pyqt                      5.9.2            py39h23ab428_6    defaults
pyrsistent                0.18.0           py39hca72f7f_0    defaults
pysocks                   1.7.1            py39hecd8cb5_0    defaults
python                    3.9.7                h88f2d9e_1    defaults
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
python-libarchive-c       2.9                pyhd3eb1b0_1    defaults
python.app                3                py39hca72f7f_0    defaults
pytz                      2021.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
pyyaml                    6.0              py39hca72f7f_1    defaults
pyzmq                     22.3.0           py39he9d5cce_2    defaults
qt                        5.9.7                h468cd18_1    defaults
qtpy                      1.10.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
readline                  8.1                  h9ed2024_0    defaults
requests                  2.26.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
ripgrep                   12.1.1                        0    defaults
ruamel_yaml               0.15.100         py39h9ed2024_0    defaults
send2trash                1.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1    defaults
setuptools                58.0.4           py39hecd8cb5_0    defaults
sip                       4.19.13          py39h23ab428_0    defaults
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
sniffio                   1.2.0            py39hecd8cb5_1    defaults
soupsieve                 2.3.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
sqlite                    3.36.0               hce871da_0    defaults
sympy                     1.9              py39hecd8cb5_0    defaults
tbb                       2021.4.0             haf03e11_0    defaults
terminado                 0.9.4            py39hecd8cb5_0    defaults
testpath                  0.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
tk                        8.6.11               h7bc2e8c_0    defaults
tornado                   6.1              py39h9ed2024_0    defaults
tqdm                      4.62.3             pyhd3eb1b0_1    defaults
traitlets                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
tzdata                    2021e                hda174b7_0    defaults
ujson                     4.0.2            py39h23ab428_0    defaults
urllib3                   1.26.7             pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
webencodings              0.5.1            py39hecd8cb5_1    defaults
wheel                     0.37.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1    defaults
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1            py39hecd8cb5_0    defaults
xlrd                      2.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
xmltodict                 0.12.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
xz                        5.2.5                h1de35cc_0    defaults
yaml                      0.2.5                haf1e3a3_0    defaults
zeromq                    4.3.4                h23ab428_0    defaults
zipp                      3.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
zlib                      1.2.11               h4dc903c_4    defaults
zstd                      1.4.9                h322a384_0    defaults
```

also, i tried to `conda update anaconda`, and i got the **PackageNotInstalledError**

```
>>>conda update anaconda
PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: /Users/usrname/anaconda3
  package name: anaconda
```

but i think anaconda exists in my conda env,

```
╰─➤  conda list --name base conda                                                                                                                                             
# packages in environment at /Users/usrname/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
anaconda-client           1.9.0            py39hecd8cb5_0    defaults
anaconda-navigator        2.1.1                    py39_0    defaults
conda                     4.11.0           py39hecd8cb5_0    defaults
conda-build               3.21.7           py39hecd8cb5_0    defaults
conda-content-trust       0.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
conda-package-handling    1.7.3            py39h9ed2024_1    defaults
conda-repo-cli            1.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
conda-token               0.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
```

Comment: My first suspicion would be that those are packages that you installed via `pip install` instead of `conda install`.  Could you edit your question and include the information of `conda list --show-channel-urls`?

Comment: @cel Sure, I have added the related information. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I think the problem you're having is functionally the same what I wrote here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55144561/anaconda-navigator-does-not-update-packages/64577268#64577268). The answer involves deactivating anaconda.