# Anaconda unable to update version or jupyter core packages

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, conda

I want my anaconda and jupyter configuration to be most up to date. I've followed the common advice which is a combination of `$ conda update conda` + `$ conda update anaconda` + `$ conda update --all` but when I list the core packages `$ jupyter --version` I get the same thing everytime:

```
IPython          : 7.29.0
ipykernel        : 6.4.1
ipywidgets       : 7.6.5
jupyter_client   : 6.1.12
jupyter_core     : 4.8.1
jupyter_server   : 1.4.1
jupyterlab       : 3.2.1
nbclient         : 0.5.3
nbconvert        : 6.1.0
nbformat         : 5.1.3
notebook         : 6.4.5
qtconsole        : 5.1.1
traitlets        : 5.1.0
```

I know these aren't the up to date versions of these packages.  If I try to upgrade an individual package I get

```
$ conda update jupyterlab
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: - 

Updating jupyterlab is constricted by 

anaconda -> requires jupyterlab==3.2.1=pyhd3eb1b0_1

If you are sure you want an update of your package either try `conda update --all` or install a specific version of the package you want using `conda install <pkg>=<version>`

done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

What is going on?

Comment: You show running `conda update all` not `conda update --all`. Is that a typo?

Comment: I am struggling with this same issue. Checking `conda list anaconda$` reveals anaconda is at version 2021.11, whereas the current version is 2022.05. I am wondering if that is the issue, but `conda updata anaconda`  reports `All requested packages already installed`

Comment: Does this solve your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55144561/anaconda-navigator-does-not-update-packages/64577268#64577268

Comment: I have used elsevers answer for now but will try the above next time around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating to the latest version of Anaconda seems to fix this:

```
conda install anaconda=2022.05
```

I now get the following jupyter versions (`jupyter --version`)

```
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.2.0
ipykernel        : 6.9.1
ipywidgets       : 7.6.5
jupyter_client   : 6.1.12
jupyter_core     : 4.9.2
jupyter_server   : 1.13.5
jupyterlab       : 3.3.2
nbclient         : 0.5.13
nbconvert        : 6.4.4
nbformat         : 5.3.0
notebook         : 6.4.8
qtconsole        : 5.3.0
traitlets        : 5.1.1
```

You can find a list of all available anaconda versions [here](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/).